# Paperclip.interpolates randomly not returning a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have the following paperclip setup in my model:

```
  #Paperclip for photo
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => {
                      :large => '1024x758>',
                      :medium => "200x150#",
                      :small => "50x50>"
                    },
                    :default_style => :original,
                    :default_url => '/images/:attachment/default_:style.png',
                    :path => ":instance_id/:attachment/:id/:version/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml'),
                    :s3_protocol => 'https'
```

for instance_id I have the following:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :instance_id do |attachment, style|

  def instance_id(attachment, style)
    attachment.instance.instance_id
  end

end
```

What's happening is when I first fire up the server, I'm noticing 404s with my images. I had thought that was Amazon S3, but then I looked into the URLs, and noticed that sometimes instance_id is not being returned by Paperclip.interpolates.

Any idea why? Have you experienced anything like this?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you specified the code for Paperclip.interpolates :instenace_id ? Because if it is not always returned, it does not seem like it is correctly required and run during server restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, then the following should work:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :instance_id do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.instance_id
end
```

FYI: your interpolates proc defines a method, but doesn't actually do something...

Hope this helps,

Peter

Comment: Thanks, the above works. Only time will tell if that prevents the broken urls.